# Forwarding call recordings in Twilio for Zoho

Tags: twilio, zoho, voicemail

I use Twilio and Zoho Phonebridge for inbound and outbound calling to customers. I use Zoho's built in IVR which works well, but has gaps.  The main gap is when I get a voicemail, I need to login to Twilio to get it and that's a time sink.  I would like Twilio to email (or text, for all I care) those messages to me, transcribed or not. Problem is, I cannot modify the code provided by Zoho, so I need to have the function carry out in parallel.  I'm not sure where to start.  I can do code snippets easily enough, but I seems I need to replace the "Voice Configuration - Request URL", which kills the IVR.

Any help?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I can help with Twilio things, but I don't know about Zoho. You say you can provide a URL, is there documentation for that that I can take a look at?

Comment: Hi philnash.  Just saw your reply.  Code is https://www.zohoapis.com/ctiapi/xml/twiliocall/twilio?zapikey=XXX.  I'd love to add my own TWIML to email Call Recordings, but Twilio doesn't appear to allow me to run more than one webhook against one number.  I wonder if I could 'borrow' the API above and modify it?  The only 'docs' I know of are here: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/crm/extensions/telephony/articles/integrate-with-twilio#Edit_or_Remove_a_Phone_Number

Comment: I'm afraid the Zoho system looks like it is relatively closed and we can't inject things into it. I would raise this as a feature request with Zoho, I can't think of another way around this.